# Video (webm) is not loaded in codepen

Tags: javascript, html

Any idea why my video not loading in code pen?

```
<source src="https://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/downtown-los-angeles.webm">
```

The direct link which is https://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/downtown-los-angeles.webm is working fine in a new tab

https://codepen.io/eldyvoon/pen/kXVjYK

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <iframe src="https://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/downtown-los-angeles.webm">
 </iframe>
```

Comment: I know iframe but this is not the answer